# Which limit laws are applied here?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to learn some calculus and I see this in my textbook:

[image]

Why does

$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{-\sin^2\theta}{\theta\cdot ( \cos\theta + 1)}$$

$$ = $$

$$ -\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} \cdot \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta + 1}$$

**My question is about pulling out the negative sign from the numerator in the line 2 lines above this one to the line right above this one where the negative sign is outside of the limits**

Is it because: $$-\sin^2\theta = $$ 
$$(-1)\cdot (\sin^2\theta)$$

and so when we take the limit of the numerator:

$$\begin{align} \lim_{\theta \to 0}(-1)(\sin^2\theta) &= \\ \lim_{\theta \to 0} (-1) \cdot \lim_{\theta \to 0} (\sin^2\theta) &= \\ -1 \cdot \lim_{\theta \to 0} (\sin^2\theta) \end{align}$$

Is that right? Is that how we pull out the negative sign?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to n} c \cdot f(x) = c \cdot \lim_{x \to n} f(x)$ If $c$ is some constant

Comment: yes, your argument is essentially correct. But nobody writes it so elaborate. You just pull out the $-1$ as a negative upfront.

Comment: It should be pointed out, though, that in this calculation there's no "$\lim\limits_{\theta\to0}(-\sin^2\theta)$". There's $\lim\limits_{\theta\to0}\frac{-\sin^2\theta}{\theta(\cos\theta+1)}$, and we don't set up the limits of the numerator and denominator separately, because that would result in division by zero. That being said, conceptually your general understanding is correct -- we take out a constant factor of $-1$, as the previous commenters have already explained.

Comment: @imranfat shouldn't I know why we can pull it out though?

Comment: Everything that is multiplying and doesn't depend on $\theta$ is constant and can go out of the limit. It doesn't matter if it is $(-1)$ or, for example, a function of another variable, like $\sin(\varphi)$.

Comment: @Jwan622 The limit of a product is the product of the limits with the condition the limit of each product exists. That is the rule you ought to dig into.